# In a subshell, how to read an environment variable from the calling shell?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, ls, subshell

For the obvious reason I do not want to `export COLUMNS` in my normal bash shell.

However for the purpose of one particular subshell, I need access to the value of COLUMNS of its parent. In other words, in a regular bash shell, I want to call a shell script that uses `ls -Cw $COLUMNS`, with the value of `$COLUMNS` from its parent.

Is there any way to access a parent's environment variables other than them being exported by the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  But there are ways to get the number of columns other than environment variables.  For example

```
COLUMNS=$(tput cols)
```